# Scroll over Jquery tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this jquery tooltip. I am using it for displaying long texts of a gridview column. The tooltip is displayed normally. Also the scrollbars are displayed but when I try to move the cursor and scroll over the tooltip, the tooltip disappears. How can this solved?
My tooltip code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { 
        $(document).tooltip({ 
            show: { 
                effect: "slideDown", 
                delay: 250
            },  
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-tooltip {    
        max-width: 500px; 
        max-height:300px; 
        overflow:auto; 
        position:absolute;   
    } 
    .style22
    {
        width: 70px;
    }
    .style25
    {
        width: 97px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you add this to JsFiddle.net ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tRgd6/

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to this

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

The tooltip is designed to fade on mouse out from the control. If you want the information not to vanish, consider using a popover

Example: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers